# MakeGenericType() actually makes an object, and I cannot use the type's methods

Tags: c#, generics

What it boils down to is that I'm trying to make a Generic and while the type shows up correctly at runtime, during compile time its still `object`, and so I cannot use any of the generic type's methods.

thanks to brainless coder on a previous question I'm able to move forward a bit

---

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kup10L)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sample = new Baz<List<Foo>>();
        sample.DoSomething();
    }

    public class Foo
    {
    }


    public class Bar<T>
    {
        public void Boom()
        {
        }
    }


    public class Baz<T>
    {
        public void DoSomething(){
            if (typeof(T).Name == "List`1")
            {
                var typeName = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().Single().FullName;
                var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
                var genericRepoType = typeof(Bar<>);
                var specificRepoType = genericRepoType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
                var genericBar = Activator.CreateInstance(specificRepoType);
                Console.WriteLine(genericBar.GetType().Name); // Shows Bar`1
                // but at compile time its foo is still an object
                genericBar.Boom(); 
                //will error with 'object' does not contain a definition for Boom
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What _exactly_ to you want to do with the object - if you _know_ it's of a particular type then just _cast it_.  If you _don't_ know the type, how is the compiler supposed to know?

Comment: @DStanley there are various entities that can be passed in, so aside from the type being some sort of entity class (person, dog, cat, etc..) I don't known which type it will be.

Comment: You could look into `dynamic` (using `dynamic genericBar = ...`), but I'm not a fan of using dynamic code when you have the option of strong types. It's unclear if you do or not. Maybe you really want a generic method? (`public void DoSomething<T>() where T : new()` if you need to do `new T()`)

Comment: You should cast it to the base type of your entity and work with that

Comment: @ton.yeung Then how do you expect to call methods on it?  What would you expect `genericBar.Boom();` to do if T were `List<Cat>`?

Comment: Reflection is turtles all the way down, you'd have to use genericBar.GetType().GetMethod("Boom").  Using *dynamic* is the very obvious alternative to stop that turtle.

Comment: @HansPassant But if you don't know what the type is (hence the need for reflection), how do you know that you can call `Boom` successfully, either at compile-time _or_ run-time?

Comment: How do you know to pass "Boom" to GetMethod()?  You have to know *something*.

Comment: I know that Bar has method Boom, as for T, its basically a value object or data transfer object, no behavior. What's Important is that I know I need Bar and that Bar has Boom, but its also a generic so I need to pass that in. Or at least, that's my understanding of how these things work.

Comment: @DStanley it should still go Boom (poor cat).

Comment: @31eee384 Hans thanks the dynamic part lets me compile but for some reason when it tries to create the instance it errors out. I think this works, though. I'll continue debugging in a few hours, so thanks in the mean time.

Comment: @ton.yeung Is there a base type that has a `Boom` method or does each type implement its own.  If it's the latter then dynamic is the cleanest solution, dangerous as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a very questionable design, but if you must, `dynamic` neatly solves your problem.

```
public static void Main() {
    var sample = new Baz<List<Foo>>();
    sample.DoSomething();
}

public class Foo { }

public class Bar<T> {
    public void Boom() {
        Console.WriteLine("I am booming");
    }
}


public class Baz<T> {
    public void DoSomething() {
        var typeName = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().Single().FullName;
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        var genericRepoType = typeof(Bar<>);
        var specificRepoType = genericRepoType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
        dynamic genericBar = Activator.CreateInstance(specificRepoType);
        Console.WriteLine(genericBar.GetType().Name); 

        genericBar.Boom();
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uPpfJa

Alternatively, you could declare an `IBar` interface.

```
public class Bar<T> : IBar {
    public void Boom() {
        Console.WriteLine("I am booming");
    }
}

interface IBar {
    void Boom();
}

...

var genericBar = (IBar)Activator.CreateInstance(specificRepoType);
```